# Insert quotes in the string using index python

Tags: python, string, replace, insert

I want to insert quotes(`""`) around the date and text in the string (which is in the file `input.txt`). Here is my input file:

```
created_at : October 9, article :   ISTANBUL — Turkey is playing a risky game of chicken in its negotiations with NATO partners who want it to join combat operations against the Islamic State group — and it’s blowing back with violence in Turkish cities. As the Islamic militants rampage through Kurdish-held Syrian territory on Turkey’s border, Turkey says it won’t join the fight unless the U.S.-led coalition also goes after the government of Syrian President Bashar Assad.
created_at : October 9, article :    President Obama chairs a special meeting of the U.N. Security Council last month. (Timothy A. Clary/AFP/Getty Images)  When it comes to President Obama’s domestic agenda and his maneuvers to (try to) get things done, I get it. I understand what he’s up to, what he’s trying to accomplish, his ultimate endgame. But when it comes to his foreign policy, I have to admit to sometimes thinking “whut?” and agreeing with my colleague Ed Rogers’s assessment on the spate of books criticizing Obama’s foreign policy stewardship.
```

I want to put quotes around the date and text as follows:

```
created_at : "October 9", article :   "ISTANBUL — Turkey is playing a risky game of chicken in its negotiations with NATO partners who want it to join combat operations against the Islamic State group — and it’s blowing back with violence in Turkish cities. As the Islamic militants rampage through Kurdish-held Syrian territory on Turkey’s border, Turkey says it won’t join the fight unless the U.S.-led coalition also goes after the government of Syrian President Bashar Assad".
created_at : "October 9", article :    "President Obama chairs a special meeting of the U.N. Security Council last month. (Timothy A. Clary/AFP/Getty Images)  When it comes to President Obama’s domestic agenda and his maneuvers to (try to) get things done, I get it. I understand what he’s up to, what he’s trying to accomplish, his ultimate endgame. But when it comes to his foreign policy, I have to admit to sometimes thinking “whut?” and agreeing with my colleague Ed Rogers’s assessment on the spate of books criticizing Obama’s foreign policy stewardship".
```

Here is my code which finds the index for comma(`,` after the date) and index for the article and then by using these, I want to insert quotes around the date. Also I want to insert quotes around the text, but how to do this?

```
f = open("input.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    article_pos = line.find("article")
    print article_pos
    comma_pos = line.find(",")
    print comma_pos
```

Comment: @Begueradj: I don't think quoting articles that he presumably pulled from some news feed that he's trying to process really counts as pushing politics.

Answer (score 1):

While you *can* do this with low-level operations like `find` and slicing, that's really not the easy or idiomatic way to do it.

First, I'll show you how to do it your way:

```
comma_pos = line.find(", ")
first_colon_pos = line.find(" : ")
second_colon_pos = line.find(" : ", comma_pos)
line = (line[:first_colon_pos+3] + 
        '"' + line[first_colon_pos+3:comma_pos] + '"' +
        line[comma_pos:second_colon_pos+3] +
        '"' + line[second_colon_pos+3:] + '"')
```

But you can more easily just split the line into bits, munge those bits, and join them back together:

```
dateline, article = line.split(', ', 1)
key, value = dateline.split(' : ')
dateline = '{} : "{}"'.format(key, value)
key, value = article.split(' : ')
article = '{} : "{}"'.format(key, value)
line = '{}, {}'.format(dateline, article)
```

And then you can take the repeated parts and refactor them into a simple function so you don't have to write the same thing twice (which may come in handy if you later need to write it four times).

It's even easier using a regular expression, but that might not be as easy to understand for a novice:

```
line = re.sub(r'(.*?:\s*)(.*?)(\s*,.*?:\s*)(.*)', r'\1"\2"\3"\4"', line)
```

This works by capturing everything up to the first `:` (and any spaces after it) in one group, then everything from there to the first comma in a second group, and so on:

```
(.*?:\s*)(.*?)(\s*,.*?:\s*)(.*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Uv5cj4Yr1CGO8HMn)

Notice that the regex has the advantage that I can say "any spaces after it" very simply, while with `find` or `split` I had to explicitly specify that there was exactly one space on either side of the colon and one after the comma, because searching for "0 or more spaces" is a lot harder without some way to express it like `\s*`.

Comment: what if there are commas in the article text?

Comment: @MattDMo: Since the first version only does `.find(', ')` once, the second version uses `.split(', ', 1)`, and the third version doesn't have a global repeat on anything with a comma, none of them care about any commas after the first one.

Comment: @snehaulal: Ah, that's because whatever you're using to read the rows is including the newline as part of the line. You can either `rstrip` them off at read time and re-add them at write time, or search for the `'\n'` the same way you search for everything else, or just use `:-1] + '"\n')` instead of `:] + '"')` (or equivalent for the other two answers). As long as you understand how any of these three work, you should be able to figure out how to extend it; if you don't understand any of them, don't use them, ask questions about what you're stuck on.

Comment: @abarnert :thanks for your help, but it just takes one line, and my input file is 50 mb in size.. How to deal with this?

Comment: @snehaulal: You run this code, or something similar, on each line (e.g., inside a `for line in f:` loop), and it gives you a modified line which you can do anything you want with (e.g., `print` it, or `write` it to a different file).

Comment: @ abarnert : thank you for all your help, problem solved.Appreciate it!!!. Can I vote for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at the regex library `re`.
E.g.

```
>>> import re
>>> print(re.sub(r'created_at:\s(.*), article:\s(.*)',
...              r'created_at: "\1", article: "\2"',
...              'created_at: October 9, article: ...'))
created_at: "October 9", article: "..."
```

The first param to `re.sub` is the pattern you are trying to match. The parens `()` capture the matches and can be used in the second argument with `\1`. The third argument is the line of text.